# Problema con instancia de arreglos

Tags: java, jsp

Hola estoy tratando de hacer unos arreglos y hacer una instancia pero no todas las variables tienen arreglos. Este es mi código:

```
  @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    private String Nombre;
    private String Titulo;
    private String Autor;
    private String Asunto;
    private String Descripcion;
    private String Contenido;
    private String[] Nombres;
    private String[] Valores;
    private List<File> Adjuntos;
    //private File  Adjuntos;



 ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

            creacion_PDF crea = new creacion_PDF(
                    m.getNombre(),
                    m.getTitulo(),
                    m.getAutor(),
                    m.getAsunto(),
                    m.getDescripcion(),
                    m.getContenido(),
                    m.getNombres(),//estos me aparecen en rojo
                    m.getValores(),//estos me aparecen en rojo
                    m.getAdjuntos());
```

Comment: Hola Kevin, bienvenido. ¿Cuando te refieres a que "te aparecen en rojo" te refieres a que el IDE te marca un error verdad? ¿Podrías indicarnos el error explícito que te muestra? ¿Podrías compartirnos el código de la clase creacion_PDF ?

Comment: el error que me dice es esto incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
----

Comment: estos me aparecen en rojo con ese comentario                m.getNombres(),
m.getValores(),

Comment: private String[] Nombres;
    private String[] Valores;

Comment: El problema es que los métodos m.getNombres() y m.getValores() te están devolviendo un único string. Y la clase creacion_PDF espera como parámetros arreglos de strings. Hay que revisar cuál esta mal, si los parámetros deben ser strings, o si los métodos getNombres() y getValores deberían devolver arreglos de strings. Por eso te pido que nos muestres el código (en tu pregunta, no como un comentario) de la clase creacion_PDF y de los métodos getNombres y getValores.

Comment: ps de verían tener los areglos porque nombres y valores no van a recibir un único valor si no mas el problema es cuando quiero ese arreglo  pero no se hacerlo!

Comment: Hay que modificar la clase creacion_PDF para que en los parámetros del constructor reciba arreglos de string entonces. Para que veas que funciona con un único string, prueba reemplazar m.getNombres y m.getValores con el string "nombre1" y el string "valor1" y verás que ya no te marca el error.

Comment: ya lo hice y funciono pero me puso un pequeño problema

Comment: private void propiedades() {
        if (Valores.length()!= 0) {
             documento.addHeader(this.getNombres(), this.getValores());
            }
    }

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable Valores of type String[]